# Shrinking the co-ordinates into a unique number

Tags: latitude-longitude, gpx

I have a bunch of data's in my gpx files. I would like to shrink those bulk data's(co-ordinates) into a single ID or sort of something. any suggestions?

Comment: Do you just want a unique identifier for each point? Could you just index them?

Comment: As you mentioned, I would require a unique identifier for each track. Here each track is saved as a single gpx file. Next thing, which I wished to do is, consider all the gpx files, which is recorded in a local vicinity and give them a single identity to all of them.

Answer (score 1):

You might use Geohash, Military Grid Reference System (MGRS), or Natural Area Code (NAC).